# sort datetimestamp column in a csv file from the command line

Tags: command-line, date, sort, csv, timestamps

I have a csv file contains a datetime column format as

```
1   Mon Mar 02 07:42:29 UT 2020
2   Tue Mar 03 09:02:09 UT 2020
3   Mon Mar 02 01:21:29 UT 2020
```

I am trying to use the sort, but I dont think my setting is right. Also, not sure how to include day of the week.

```
sort -t , -k 2 test.csv -o sorted.csv
```

Comment: @steeldriver. Thanks. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
$ cat file.csv
1,Mon Mar 02 07:42:29 UT 2020
2,Tue Mar 03 09:02:09 UT 2020
3,Mon Mar 02 01:21:29 UT 2020
```

then using `csvsort` from the [Python csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
$ csvsort --no-header-row --datetime-format "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y" --columns 2 file.csv
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/agate/table/from_csv.py:88: RuntimeWarning: Column names not specified. "('a', 'b')" will be used as names.
a,b
3,Mon Mar 02 01:21:29 UT 2020
1,Mon Mar 02 07:42:29 UT 2020
2,Tue Mar 03 09:02:09 UT 2020
```